# Vertex in a graph whose stabilizer (in a given group $\Gamma$ of automorphisms) does not fix any neighbour vertex?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I know next to nothing about graph theory, but I did recently use the concept of graphs and groups acting on them to formalize the proof of a statement that has a priori nothing to do with graphs. 
I want to avoid reinventing the wheel, so I wonder whether the following phenomenon has an established name or has been studied in the literature:

Let $G$ be a (finite, connected) graph and let $\Gamma$ be a subgroup of the automorphism group of $G$. 
Let $v$ be a vertex in $G$ and let $\Gamma_v$ be the stabilizer subgroup of $v$ in $\Gamma$.

> **Question:** 
>   *Does there exist a standard notation for the property of $v$ that for any neighboring vertex $w$ of $v$, there is a $\gamma \in \Gamma_v$ such that $\gamma(w) \neq w$ ?*

I mainly need this property in the case of cyclic graphs or trees, so a property that coincides with the described one in these cases will also be useful.
My ad hoc notation for a vertex $v$ with the property as mentioned above is a *$\Gamma$-pivot vertex*. I am open for other suggestions of names should there not exist an established name.

**Examples**:

- If $G$ is a finite tree, then no matter the group $\Gamma$, there is at most one $\Gamma$-pivot vertex.
- If $G$ is a circular graph and $\Gamma$ is the full dihedral group, then every vertex is a $\Gamma$-pivot vertex. If $\Gamma$ is a subgroup of order $2$ of the full dihedral group (a reflection and the identity), then there are at most two $\Gamma$-pivot vertices.

Comment: I never came across a name for this property. The first thing that came to my mind was "all vertices in an arc-transitive graphs (of degree $\ge 2$) have this property", but this is something strictly stronger.

Comment: I don't know about a standard terminology, but it would be equivalent to say that $v$ is an isolated vertex of $G^{\Gamma_v}$.